# Exporting .py using pyinstaller throws import pandas error

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I have a simple script named Hello.py with the following code:

```
import pandas
print("hello world, pandas was imported successfully!")
```

my goal is to create a .exe from this file using pyinstaller. However, after running

```
python -m PyInstaller Hello.py
```

and running the generated .exe, I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried lots of things, hooks, changin the .spec file... but none of them worked. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried installing pandas on your own system? Does the script run without the `-m PyInstaller` bit? Try `pip install pandas`.

Comment: If I install pandas and then I run the script it works, but my idea was to export the file to a .exe so it could be used in another system as a standalone program.

Comment: Does it not do that now? You can update the question to reflect this new problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip install pandas` or try `pip uninstall typing`.

Hope it helps.